# Can a subplot within a python-Matplotlib subplots be used for bullet statements?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I'd like to make a [2,2] subplot of charts/graphs using the first three open plots for the graphs and the 4 spot for bullet points about the graphs/charts.  Is this possible using python/matplotlib?

Take for example the code below:

```
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
fig.suptitle("Owner Occupied Loss Ratio")

sns.barplot(ax = axes[0,0], x=decile_oo['decile'], y=np.round((decile_oo['NonCAT Loss Ratio']*100),2), color = 'blue')
# g.bar_label(ax.containers[0])

sns.barplot(ax = axes[0,1], x=decile_oo['decile'], y=np.round((decile_oo['NonCAT Frequency']*100),2), color = 'red')
# f.bar_label(ax.containers[0])

sns.barplot(ax = axes[1,0], x=decile_oo['decile'], y=np.round((decile_oo['NonCAT Severity']*100),2), color = 'green')
# i.bar_label(ax.containers[0])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

That produced the below graphic.

[image]

I'd like that blank graph in position [1,1] to have bullet points I type out instead of a blank graph.  Is this possible?

Comment: While not crucial for answering the question, note that your code runs into an Exception: `NameError: name 'decile_oo' is not defined`.

Comment: I think if you erase the grid and ticks on the axes[1,1] and use annotations, you can make bullet points.